# Android Facebook SSO for server side authentication

Tags: android, facebook, single-sign-on

I am using FB SSO for an Android App and I would like to use the Facebook ID to authenticate my users when they upload data to my server. I imagine I should send the OAuth token when making the call to the server. Any examples out there that could help me get started?

Thanks for any pointers.

Comment: Do you have an solution for this? I have the same requirement..

Comment: Check out [***this***](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/build/#sso) Android tutorial from facebook, I think might be helpful to you and
[single sign-on Best Practice](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/640/) (SSO)

Answer (score 4):

I have faced the same problem a while ago.
In the end, I did it using the following way:

I get the token via Facebook Android SDK and pass it to my server with the users email address and facebook id. Server tries to get users email address using the token. If the email addresses match, the user has authenticated.

Comment: can you share this in detail or could share some code on this? I have a question similar related to this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25215610/facebook-login-in-andorid-with-different-devices

Comment: This answer doesn't give any details at all.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please clarify further, you want to authenticate user on your server via Facebook ID? The access token received via SSO will allow you to call graph apis, FQL query etc. which may require special permissions depending upon what you want to do.

More on Android SDK: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/#android

More on Permissiosn: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/

Comment: I think the root of the problem is that the Facebook Android SDK authenticates the client, but he also wants to authenticate the user on his own server (when uploading data).  Sure the client has the access token via SSO, but how does the server safely know that the user is authenticated.